# whats the best practice to do a long query like deletion of big chunks in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, query

On production servers I need sometime to delete a few 100,000s of rows . The query is optimized but deleting at once will cause servers freeze so I do it manually in chunks deleting for example 5000 rows each time. To allow the server to clear pending queries and to make the table locks less obvious to end users.
I use MyISAM engine.

Isnt there a tool /command/ method that does long queries like this in low precedence or in chunks or in a way that doesnt get the server stuck in cases where its OK if it will take a long time to complete?

whats the best practices?

Comment: How do you do this know? Do you use some kind of loop for deleting rows, or deleting everything with 1 query?

Comment: I do a query with limit and match the limit so the server will return after for example 10 seconds. and repeat the query manually

Comment: Ahh, okay, I hoped you were using a loop, then **START TRANSACTION** and **COMMIT** speed things up considerably :)

Comment: If you don't want it to freeze, stop using MyISAM.  Changes to a MyISAM table lock the entire table for every operation.  InnoDB (and others but InnoDB being the most commonly used) use row-based locks for most operations.  Also / alternatively, partition based on what you're matching for the delete and just drop the partition.  Dropping a partition will momentarily lock the full table (as it's technically a change to the table structure, not a data change) but it should be far faster than deleting every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the `LOW_PRIORITY` keyword to your `DELETE` query and see how that does.  For example `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM tablenamegoeshere ...`

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html for more details.

Comment: I will try that